# Delete ASP.NET user account when customer record is deleted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you delete an ASP.NET User Account, when a customer deletes his user profile; any advice on how to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

If your customer account has records that are still associated to it you probably don't want to delete the user so as to maintain data integrity. Removing the actual aspnet membership record should really be a administrative exercise.

In my opinion you should just set the `.IsApproved` flag on the user object to false and have a report that allows

1. a manual method of making sure that an account can be deleted without affecting records (orphaned data) or
2. create a job that can safely delete the user account when `IsApproved == false`.

My vote is against deletion entirely so as to not leave your database in an inconsistent state

Answer (score 1):

You should set the MembershipUser.IsApproved to false and call [Membership.UpdateUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx) to save the update.

```
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser("MyUserName");
if (membershipUser!= null){
    membershipUser.IsApproved = false;
    Membership.UpdateUser(membershipUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the API and delete the account? Sounds trivial. Put it into your workflow.